# Archiving table data into another table in Rails

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-4, archive

I have a table in my db holding lots of data and search query takes time, so that i want to archive some old data into another table, I searched and found some gems and solutions to add column in the same table and make some sort of scopes in model but i want that old data to move another table as archived data. Is there any gem you guys know or way to deal with this issue ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you considered something like Elasticsearch instead?

Comment: its cool but i am looking something like to play with models or db to separate archived data into another model or table.

Comment: @Awais: did you find a nice way to do this?

Comment: @Awais did you find anything useful in order to achieve it in a best way ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a table with entries that are getting quite big. I looked at the model and realized that I only have belongs_to relationships on it. The implication is that I have no other tables with dependencies on the table I want to archive.

The entries are for calculating a user's balance over time and thus the balance is cached in the table over time. Which will be the main difficulty imo.

1. I'm thinking of creating a table and model ArchivedEntry with the same relationships.
2. Periodically, probably one time per year at my current rate of growth I will make rake task that migrates the old records.
3. I will create final record in the archived table and a new record in the main table that will be the balance transfer from the archived table to the existing table.

For the time being I'll be able to query the archived table but as it gets too big I am thinking of pulling the table out entirely and migrating it to a seperate service.

This will probably affect individual validations and all of the relationships will have to be looked at again. However, the data should stay relatively static and shouldn't need to change.